# How to get the Images related to a Location search in ios

Tags: ios, mapkit

I am creating an iPad `MasterDetail` application based on map search.
`MasterViewController` performs a search on the keyword and passes results to the `TableView` and `DetailView` and provides a map with the selected item from the `MasterView`. I want to add the images related to the searched location in a subview when I select the `annotation`.

Comment: first of all do R&D on this https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/ it will solve all your problem @sudheesh

Comment: Thanks @Anil Prasad, I've researched place photo documentation but stuck with JSON output, how should I get the photo_reference from the JSON output. Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/photo?maxwidth=400&photoreference=CoQBegAAAFg5U0y-iQEtUVMfqw4KpXYe60QwJC-wl59NZlcaxSQZNgAhGrjmUKD2NkXatfQF1QRap-PQCx3kMfsKQCcxtkZqQ&sensor=true&key=AddYourOwnKeyHere

Comment: place ur photo_reference id in this api @sudheesh

Comment: Thanks @Anil Prasad, got answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the way that I,ve solved the problem.

```
NSString *nearBySearch = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=%f,%f&radius=200&key=%@",_mapItem.placemark.location.coordinate.latitude, _mapItem.placemark.location.coordinate.longitude, kGOOGLE_API_KEY];
NSURL *searchURL = [NSURL URLWithString:nearBySearch];    
NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: searchURL];
NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization
                      JSONObjectWithData:data
                      options:kNilOptions
                      error:&error];
NSArray* placeResults = [json objectForKey:@"results"];
NSDictionary *place = [placeResults objectAtIndex:i];
NSArray *photos = [place objectForKey:@"photos"];    
NSArray *referencArray = [photoDetails objectForKey:@"photo_reference"];
NSString *photoURLString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/photo?maxwidth=300&maxheight=300&photoreference=%@&key=%@", [referenceArray objectAtIndex:i], kGOOGLE_API_KEY];
NSURL *photoURL = [NSURL URLWithString:photoURLString];
NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:photoURL];
placeImage = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
```

Thanks @Anil Prasad for giving valuable link and help.