# Swift local place Image

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, mapkit

I recently switched from using `Google Maps` to `MKMapkit`.
What is the best way to retrieve images from place search. I realize that Mac map usees Yelp but I'm not sure if that is part of `MKMapkit` API.

Comment: iOS MKMapKit API has not the same features as Google Maps, so you should still use big G, here's a useful example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25359890/3724800